# What is the difference between these two mongoose schema presentations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to figure out the difference between two situations in which to present Mongoose schemas. I'm looking to create a post under which users can leave comments. In one case I have the Comment schema in the same file as the (main) Post schema as seen below, in case 1, while the other case involves having separate files for the respective (Comment and Post) schemas, as seen in case 2. The Comment schema is duly referenced in the Post schema.

Initially, I created and saved a post (then added a couple of dummy comments) using the first method/case. Afterwards, after separating the two schemas, I was unable to add/fetch comments to/from the database. So, what gives? I don't have the greatest of knowledge with respect to this, so would highly appreciate an explanation.

I hope I was concise enough in my description of my predicament.

Here are the relevant code snippets.

**Case 1: Comment and Post schemas in the same file**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  body: { type: String },
  addedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});

const PostSchema = new Schema({
  //...
  comments: [CommentSchema],
  //...
  },
  { 
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

export default Post;
```

**Case 2: Comment and Post schemas in separate files**

```
//comment.js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CommentSchema = new Schema({
  body: { type: String },
  addedBy: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
});

const Comment = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);

export default Comment;

/******************************************************/

//post.js

import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const PostSchema = new Schema({
  //...
  comments: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }],
  //...
  },
  { 
    timestamps: true,
  },
);

const Post = mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);

export default Post;
```

Comment: You didn't only separate the declarations into two files, you also created a separate model for comments. Which is now only referenced from the post, not contained in it. The code querying the database will need to be adapted to this change of course.

Comment: @Bergi Oh, thank you! I was a under the (false) impression that the two approaches were pretty much similar.